# iPhone Webview onBackground event?

Tags: iphone, cordova, uiwebview, mgwt

I am developing a iphone app using phonegap. Now I want to maintain a session state when the app goes into the background. I want to persist that state even if the app gets killed by the OS. (Just consider saving some variables in javascript when the app goes into background)

Is there some way I can do that? Does the UIWebView allows javascript to execute when the app is moving to background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t think that there is such an event, so I would suggest that you always save your state if you change it within your app. So you dont have to save while closing the app.

Comment: Can't we delay the process of going in the background for the app? Like may be in applicationWillResignActivity method, to give the webView a little more time to execute the instructions?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve? Maybe theres another way to do the same thing?

Comment: I know its too late, but I was hoping that someone will have an answer :). So accepting your answer that its indeed not possible, at-least not yet :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about phoneGap, but in objective-c you can add an observer (register for notifications for when the app goes into the background)

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector: @selector(enteredBackground) 
    name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
    object: nil];
```

Then create a method named enteredBackground, and you can put code like:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Do something in javascript"];
```

where you replace the `Do something in javascript` with the code you want to execute.
See this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried making a javascript call from "applicationWillResignActivity" method. While any objective-C code will run, the javascript would not run even when it was placed before the obj-c lines. So I guess the webview itself just hangs up. Is this different from the notification approach that you mentioned? I didn't try that since I thought both things are same. If have a working webview in that approach, please tell. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I didn't realise it wouldnt execute in willResignActive. The method in my answer will get called slightly later sonic guessing now that it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think there no way to achieve this. If anyone has found a solution, please share.

All I am trying to do is get the "app-going-to-the-background" event in my webview so that I can run some javascript code at that point. It is similar to running objective-c code in `applicationWillResignActivity`. So if anyone has working example of how this can be done, please reply.

Otherwise, I will have to consider this as "cant-be-done-job" :(